# What good PHP Software to create a membership site?

Tags: php

I going to be creating a membership site where you have to pay (PayPal) to access content and I am to lazy to code it myself, so I wanted to know what is a good PHP software that fits my needs? I was thinking Wordpress or Drupal but are there better alternatives?

Comment: Oh, i'm too lazy to answer this question .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked in any of the big CMS? They won't remove *all* effort but will reduce it to a minimum or provide you with modules/plugins/... that do some of the things you need.

- Drupal
- Typo3
- Jommla
- *the list goes on forever*

Good overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#PHP_2

Comment: thanks, though I am having a hard time choosing which one. I will try some out latter when I get home.